# Using a BroadcastReceiver to launch an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to update the state of a UI on receipt of a push notification. In order to do this, I need to start an `AsyncTask` that performs some network operations and then updates the UI based on the result.

According to the documentation for `BroadcastReceiver`, performing asynchronous operations within a receiver is unsafe because the process executing it may be killed as soon as `onReceive()` returns, assuming there are no other "application components" in that process.

Is the `BroadcastReceiver` running in its own process, or in the same process as the containing Activity? Since I only care about the completion of the task as long as there is a UI to update, I'm not worried about the `AsyncTask` dying if the activity is closed. Assuming the BroadcastReceiver is in the same process as the activity, does this make it okay/safe to launch the task I've described from within the receiver?

**Edit:**

To clarify, I am registering the receiver in the activity's `onResume()` and unregistering it `onPause()`, so it should only be receiving intents when the activity is already active.

Comment: Why not use a `Service` instead of BroadcastReceiver if its unsafe? It would accomplish the same thing, but without the issue you speak of.

Comment: @Andy I understand that using a `Service` will be safe in all circumstances, but I'm trying to determine whether it's really necessary in this particular case.

Comment: Well it is if you think about it. Services are perfect for running asynchronous operations. Hence why the same limitation is not present. BroadcastReceivers are mainly used for other things like when something happens in the System, not really when data is being updated through the net. Hence "Broadcast". While a `Service` is what it is, a service you are running on the side that the user does not need to know about. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You could use a handler instead to update your UI from your BroadcastReceiver. That way you're just queuing events up on your activities msg queue.

Comment: I would recommend just passing the information immediately to Activity as outlined below.  From there you can kick off whatever you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcast receiver is not running on it's own process, it's running on UI thread.

Your process will be killed after onReceive method returns only if there is no other activity or service in your app is running.

If your broadcast receiver is an instance of an inner class and only receive when your activity is active, then your process will not be killed after onReceive method returns.

Comment: [link to official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ProcessLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

If inside your `AsyncTask`, you need a context, then I think a service is better. If not, there is no problem using `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Before Honeycomb (API11), you had to use a service.

Since Honeycomb (API11), you can use [**goAsync()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync%28%29) :

> This can be called by an application in onReceive(Context, Intent) to
>   allow it to keep the broadcast active after returning from that
>   function. This does not change the expectation of being relatively
>   responsive to the broadcast (finishing it within 10s), but does allow
>   the implementation to move work related to it over to another thread
>   to avoid glitching the main UI thread due to disk IO.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is `startActivity(intent)` from the broadcast receiver.  Thats all. Inside the intent I would provide the event information you speak of, you can just set a parameter in the bundle.  You can then examine this inside the Activity `onStart()` or `onCreate()` whichever gets called.  If the flag is there, then from the `Activity` kick off the `AsyncTask`.

No need to use a service at all, with all the binding and communication limitations from service-activity.

Remember you can also `startActivityForResult()` as well.  I think that you don't want to do anything except pass and forward inside a broadcast receiver.

BTW, Activities don't need to have UI's. There can be faceless activities.

Comment: As you mentioned — _…activities don't need to have UI's_ — then I recommend him using service… I thought activities are used for UI, and services for background tasks.